# Comma Seprate Field Name in Sql Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a table Name "EmpMast"
i want to add all emp_name with comma separate like
"Mahesh,Vipul,Ritesh"
How could i do that???

Comment: You should avoid storing multiple values in one field.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're importing a CSV file. There's a good example [here](http://www.teratrax.com/articles/bulk_insert_sql_server.html)

```
BULK INSERT [orders]
FROM 'c:\orders.csv'
WITH (FIELDTERMINATOR = ',')
```

Comment: No no i want a column that return "Mahesh,Vipul,Ritesh" This result

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved using SQL Server's built-in XML capabilities:

```
SELECT
   STUFF
   (
       (
           SELECT ',' + emp_name
           FROM EmpMast
           ORDER BY emp_name
           FOR XML PATH('')
       ), 1, 1, ''
   ) AS employee_names
```

The STUFF statement here simply removes the first comma from the list.

More on FOR XML here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345137(v=sql.90).aspx
More on STUFF here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188043.aspx

I've done a full write-up on this technique here: http://davidduffett.net/post/5334646215/get-a-column-separated-list-of-values-with-for-xml